# Iterator Objects, PyCapsules, and Memory Performance

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pyqt, python-2.7

I'm working on a PyQt4 application and I've all but finished, except that there appears to be a memory leak. The code for the entire thing is rather long so I won't post all of it here. I've been using a tool called Python Memory Validator to track my application's memory allocations. I've noticed that the classes which continue to increase in number of instances after the program has initialized are, most prominently, iterators, specifically `dictionary-keyiterator`, `listiterator`, and `tupleiterator`. Besides these, the only other classes which continue to increase in number of instances are `PyCapsule` and `method-wrapper`.

I've investigated the locations where the iterators are allocated and it seems that at least tupleiterators are instantiated and never deleted every time I use the `zip()` function. Is this normal behavior or could these iterators could be the cause of the memory leak? If so, is there a workaround?

I've also investigated where PyCapsules and method-wrappers have been instantiated and both appear to be created from a method with the following code, and never deleted.

```
def importXml(self, fh):
    error = None
    try:
        handler = SaxSensorDataHandler(self)
        parser = QXmlSimpleReader()
        parser.setContentHandler(handler)
        parser.setErrorHandler(handler)
        input_ = QXmlInputSource(fh)
        self.new = True
        if not parser.parse(input_):
            if handler.errorLine == 4:
                self.new = False
            else:
                raise ValueError
    except (IOError, OSError, ValueError), e:
        error = "Failed to import file: %s" % e
    finally:
        if fh is not None:
            fh.close()
        if error is not None:
            return False, error
        if len(self.__sensors) == 0:
            return False, "Discovered no sensors connected to %s. Please check sensor connections and try again." % fh.url().host()
        self.__dirty = True
        return True, 'Discovered %d sensors connected to %s. Please press "Start" to begin taking measurements.' %(len(self.__sensors), fh.url().host())
```

This mostly consists of instantiating and using stock PyQt classes with `SaxSensorDataHandler` being a reimplemented `QXmlDefaultHandler`, and the only reimplemented methods are ones called by the XML handler while reading through XML tags. All I'm doing with these methods is assigning the retrieved information to variables and calling another method that updates the corresponding variables in the container, so this shouldn't be causing the memory leak. Could the memory leak then perhaps be caused by any known issues with PyQt4's Xml handler classes?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [gc module](http://docs.python.org/library/gc.html). To debug a leaking program call `gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_LEAK)`, and you'll get debugging output on `sys.stderr`.